# Pathfinding for enemies in unity 2d top-down game

Tags: 2d, path-finding, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a 2d top-down pc game (in unity) which requires enemy pathfinding. I found a great tutorial on that and followed it. However, it only solves half of my problem since I need the enemies to move in a loop-pattern or at least be able to continue to another target. This tutorial only shows me how the AI is going to walk from point A to B and not continuing to another point. Does anybody have an idea of how to make it work?

Here's the tutorial I followed:
http://hobblygobbly.tumblr.com/post/93960257057/how-to-setup-the-a-pathfinding-project-in-a-2d

Comment: In your place I would do the Unity's official tutorials on Navigation first. It's much simpler than A* Pathfinding Project (which is more comprehensive as for today).

Comment: I have tried to use unity's navigation but since that only works for 3d games I had to find another way.

Comment: Unity has a very good pathfinding system using navigation meshes. It works for 2d and 3d environments (I created some games). All you have to do is bake a navmesh and move the enemy's agent towards the target. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

The general solution to this is to use a list of 'waypoints'.

A,B,C,D,E

Every time an enemy reaches a waypoint (e.g. A), you set the next waypoint (B) as the new destination for that enemy.

If you have multiple enemies all following the same path, it is a good idea to be a little relaxed about 'reaching the waypoint' - by which I mean you can check if they are less than a certain distance from it and then advance to the next one.  This stops everything jamming up trying to reach the exact same point.